# How to replicate UITableViewCell imageView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list

In a normal storyboard/UIKit application, you can set the imageView of a cell in the `cellForRowAt` function as follows:

```
cell.imageView?.image = // some UIImage
```

When an imageView is set, the tableView's divider shortens to accommodate for the image, leaving no divider under the images itself, like in the default Settings app ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCL9R.png))

However, in SwiftUI, this doesn't seem to be possible. You can, of course, replicate the content of the cells with a `List` and `HStack`, but the divider extends the whole bottom of the cell.

The workarounds I've tried look something along the lines of this:

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none

struct TableView: View {
  let arr = ["Alex", "Brian", "Charlie"]
  var body: some View {
    List(arr, id: \.self) { entry in
      HStack {
        Image(systemName: "person")
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(String(entry))
          Divider()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but all of them don't align correctly [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMvpn.png).

Again, it's probably infeasible considering how SwiftUI works fundamentally and also a pretty trivial problem, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask. Fingers crossed for WWDC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `HStack` alignment to `.firstTextBaseline`.

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks. X_X

Comment: Thanks! It'll do for now and looks pretty spot-on.